# What should I do to remove the comma after the last term?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int n1, n2, temp, n, d, p;
  printf("Enter two numbers(The limits of your prime numbers): ");
  scanf("%d %d", &n1, &n2);
  if (n1>n2)
  {
      temp=n1;
      n1=n2;
      n2=temp;
  }
  printf("The prime numbers between %d and %d are: ", n1, n2);
  for(n=n1;(n<=n2)||(n<2000);++n)
  {
      p=1;
      for(d=2; d<=n/2; ++d)
      {
        if(n%d==0)
        {
          p=0;
          break;
        }
      }
      if(p==1)
      {
        if (n==1)
        {continue;}
        printf("%d",n);
        //I don't know what to put here so that the last term won't have a comma
        printf(", ");

      }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to print prime numbers between two intervals(inclusive) but the last terms always have a comma. I need a way to prevent the comma from printing after the last term. The commas are followed by a space before the next term.

### For example(My current situation):

`Input:1 10`
`Output:2, 3, 5, 7,`

```
What it should be:2, 3, 5, 7
```

I forgot to mention that once "n" exceeds 2000 it should stop printing..

Comment: 2 options come to mind. 1) don't print the text out immediately. append to a variable, then you can substring it to remove the comma before outputting. 2) check if n and d have reached there limit `if( !(((n<=n2)||(n<2000)) && d<=n/2))` should do it.

Comment: The first is the only one which is not of the form ``<comma><value>``, all the subsequent ones are. If you see it that  way, problem solved ;)

Comment: why are you use (n<2000) condition? if you use this condition then n<n2 will not effect on code.you remove it.but when you remove n<2000 then output will show like this 2, 3, 5, 7,

Comment: Ummm... I'm sorry. I thought it could only be done thru ifs and some other statements & other stuff, hence, the comment in my code in that specific location. But I think NeErAj KuMaR solved it in the simplest way. I tested it out and it works. I'm only a beginner and I just started programming the other day so I can't understand half the things most of you said but thanks for all the help. I learned more from the comment and answer sections than my own professor

Answer (score 2):

A very common problem, independent from the programming language and more of a logical thinking exercise. In this case, you can't tell when you're printing the *last* number, but you *can* tell when you print the *first*. Use that knowledge and put the `", "` *first* in your loop, omitting it on the first iteration.

*edit:* eg use a flag for this: `if (firstRun) { firstRun = 0; } else  { fputs(", ", stdout); }`

Comment: I'd probably cut the first iteration out of the loop rather than use a flag.

Comment: that's not easily applicable here because you could be in the `n`th iteration of the loop when printing out the first number. But, I wrote *eg* for a reason ;)

Answer (score 2):

Print the comma separately before the number, and have a conditional stating if this is the first prime number, don't print the comma. Otherwise print it out....

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 (n<=n2)?printf(","):(n<2000?printf(","):printf("\n"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
char *separator = "";

for (...) {
    ...
    printf("%s%d", separator, n);
    separator = ",";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

i have a great solution for your question use

printf("\b\b  ");   //2 time space after \b\b

it include before return 0; statement like :

```
 if(p==1)
  {
    if (n==1)
    {continue;}
    printf("%d",n);
    //I don't know what to put here so that the last term won't have a comma
    printf(", ");

  }
   }
 printf("\b\b  "); //here insert code 
 return 0;
```

it will help surely

Comment: downvoted -- try that with stdout redirection to a file. Really, keep your code agnostic of the actual output device, this only works with (some) ttys.

Comment: i'm not saying what are you explain for give downvote me.it's your choice.thank you but if you try with stdout then you can use dynamic array using (malloc and calloc) and that will store automatic variable value and array can also help for finding last value so then easily use stuout with error?? any doubt ??

Comment: Sorry, your comment is incomprehensible. There are two fine answers. Using dynamic allocation for this problem is possible, but way overhead. I'm commenting my downvote to give you a chance to learn (in this case, just remember there's no guarantee `stdout` will be a tty). At least you should improve your answer to state the added constraints (only works on ttys with backspace).

Comment: are you reading properly question of @Blake  .he wants code which put between two print statements.he wants code using c concept.  Blake also comment out that line is //I don't know what to put here so that the last term won't have a comma   so read properly this line

Comment: are you reading (and *understanding*) my comments? your code is broken for anything as an output device that is *not* a tty supporting backspace.

Comment: \b is use for print another character on previous position character.it can not broken.@Blake want only answer now not any concept that he discuss in question about not supporting device

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90390/discussion-between-neeraj-kumar-and-felix-palmen).